# Geometrically, why is $D4$ not equal to $S4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if there is a geometrical way of seeing that the $D4$ group (regular 4-gons) is not equal to $S4$.

Comment: Because you can't permute one pair of adjacent corners without permuting the other pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Because you can't permute one pair of adjacent corners without permuting the other pair."

- User "David Hill," in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Because $D_4$ contains much less symmetries of the square than $4!=24$. In fact, we only have $4$ rotations, and $4$ additional reflections. This is clear from the geometry.

Comment: Just... $4!=24\neq 60$.

Comment: @DavidMolano Sure ... but this is more group-theoretically than geometrically.

Comment: I suspect there was another comment there before mine, but I cannot remember.

Answer (score 1):

$D_4$ is the group of *rigid* motions, i.e. any permutation from $D_4$ will preserve the square shape. For example, you can't swap just two adjacent vertices of a square (an element of $S_4$) without deforming it into something that isn't a square.